# WordPress plugin Write User/staff ID as the same as the WordPress User ID

Tags: url-rewriting, users, id

I have a question in regards to a WordPress plugin (Bookly) that creates a Staff ID for an already created WordPress user, and hopefully, somebody may be able to help me with.

Currently Bookly adds the Staff ID incremental so each new staff ID would say Staff ID:4 then the next 5 then 6 etc,
I'm looking for some code that would take the current WordPress user's ID and add that ID as the Staff ID for that user when they are creating a Staff ID for them.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because the database table is set up to auto increment then you can't change the ID to match user ID without redesigning the database tables. This would be fine except you wouldn't be able to update the plugin without remaking the changes each time.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, would there be any other work around where i could match a users wordpress ID with their staff ID?  The issue i have is that the users profile is displayed via a template and in the template i have shorcode to dispay the users booking module via Staff ID="1" i thought if i could have the Wordpress users ID the same as the Staff ID i could use  get_userid from post / page.(<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?>  My appoligies my coding knowledge is not too advanced

Comment: How does the plugin link staff id to user id?

Comment: by username and email and contact number is the details pulled from the WP user to Create a Staff ID for the user

Comment: Well if the staff ID and user name is linked then you just retrieve the user name from the staff ID then use this function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be more helpful Ryan, I realise its less than ideal. If you post me some code I'm happy to work through it with you.

Comment: lukgoh you have been very helpful i appreshiate your guidance,  in my wordpress user database it has the colum "wp_user_id" and then  in the plugin database it has the folllowing fields "id" & "wp_user_id"  the following code is what im trying to use  where it says STAFF_MEMBER_ID  is where i am trying to get the ID from the Worpress user id and output the ID from the plugin table      <?php echo do_shortcode('[bookly-form category_id="1" service_id="4" staff_member_id="get_the_author_meta( "" ), " hide="categories,services,staff_members,week_days"]'); ?>

Comment: Do you know how to create a function?

You could use a function to retrieve the wp_user_id from staff table where id = staffmemberid then from that you will have the user id to load the data from. I would write you something but it's impossible without seeing the table names etc. 

If I were you, I would load up the functions.php page inside the bookly plugin and check to see if they already have a function for it (I would imagine they do!)

Comment: No but i can learn how to do it. TABLE "wp_ab_staff" with these colums "id" "wp_user_id" "full_name  then  2nd table name "service_finder_providers" with colums "wp_user_id" "full_name" would this help you to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_user_by_staff_id($user_ID) {

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_ab_staff WHERE wp_user_id = '$user_ID' LIMIT 1 ");

    $staff_id = $results;

    return $staff_id;
}
```

Add this to your functions.php (not Booklys!!)

Then to use it you can do this:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[bookly-form category_id="1" service_id="4" staff_member_id="'. get_user_by_staff_id(**USER ID HERE**) .'" hide="categories,services,staff_members,week_days"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i will try this now and let you know how i get on

Comment: If i insert the_author_meta($field,$user_id); where **USER ID HERE** would this pull the ID from the Url and enter it here automatically ?

Comment: From the URL? So you have something like example.com?id=ID in the url?

Comment: yea thats correct example.com/tom-smith its the user name that appears in the url

Comment: What is the get variable? So something like $name = $_GET['id'];

Comment: would i find this get variable in the functions php?  you mean to paste the above into the field where ID should be in the snippet of code you provided above correct?

Comment: You should find this get variable in the page that is being loaded (to retrieve the id from the url)

Comment: would this be the variable im searching for ?    get_user_meta($providerInfo->wp_user_id

Comment: Here is a snippet of code where it pulls other info from the same database table    <div class="provider-social clearfix">
            <ul class="social-bx list-inline">
              <?php if($providerInfo->facebook != ""){ ?>
              <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url($providerInfo->facebook); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if($providerInfo->twitter != ""){ ?>
              <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url($providerInfo->twitter); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>

Comment: You need to find where it gets $providerInfo from.

Comment: $providerinfo comes from the table  |service_finder_providers |              $name = $_GET['id'];  i thought maybe change $name to providerinfo but i get an error in the code then unfortunately :(

Comment: Sorry Ryan, what I mean is where is the query that is resulting in $providerinfo with results? Also you will get that error because you are replacing the data from $providerinfo to the $_GET variable.

Comment: @lukgoh I am having the same issue as Ryan. I have tried your code but everytime I try run it  get the following error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_user_by_staff_id()` I added the get_user_by_staff_id() function to my themes functions.php file, Im not sure where I am going wrong.